# Почему набор Android App Bundle не подписан?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console

Я генерирую `app-debug.aab` файл для публикации в google play, проблема в том, что google console пишет мне, что файл не подписан, хотя я создал ключ и генерирую `App Bundle` с подписью, выбираю ключ и ввожу пароль. Но мне выпадает ошибка "Набор Android App Bundle не подписан", когда я пытаюсь положить файл в гугловскую консоль.
На что лучше стоит обратить внимание? Я пробовал уже загружать в `console` свой ключ при помощи инструмента `pepk.jar`, все равно не получается добиться одобрения от `console`.

Comment: проверь, чтобы в сборке gradle был debuggable false

Comment: Само название файла намекает, что это debug сборка, которая по умолчанию подписывается ключом для отладки. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk